# className attribute won't take CSSProperties type - React, Material-UI, with TypeScript 4.1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am new to Material-UI. We are using withStyles to wrap the component.

I followed the docs [here](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-withstyles) to create the classes object with the correct types.

```
const classes = createStyles({
    mainDiv: {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center"
        ...
```

Then I pass those down to my component in the className attribute, like this.

```
render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return <div id="mainDiv" className={classes.mainDiv}>
        ...
```

I get a TypeScript error under className which says:

`Type 'CSSProperties | CreateCSSProperties<{}> | PropsFunc<{}, CreateCSSProperties<{}>>' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.`

This error makes sense to me because in normal JSX, the className attribute should receive a string. I find it very odd that Material-UI passes it an object, but I guess that's its special thing. So how do I let TypeScript know that this normal old div's className attribute should be the same special thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `createStyles` function doesn't create class names.  It just returns the styles that you gave it.  Its only purpose is to check the validity of the styles by forcing them to conform to the `CSSProperties` type.  Per [the docs](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#using-createstyles-to-defeat-type-widening):

> TypeScript widens the return types of function expressions. Because of this, using the `createStyles` helper function to construct your style rules object is recommended.  `createStyles` is just the identity function; it doesn't "do anything" at runtime, just helps guide type inference at compile time.

You would need to apply your styles to the `style` property rather than the `className` property:

```
return <div id="mainDiv" style={classes.mainDiv}/>
```

Or use a different function which creates `string` class names, such as [`makeStyles`](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook):

```
// creates a hook which maps props to class names
const useStyles = makeStyles(classes);

const MyComponent = (props: {}) => {
  // call the created hook with the component props
  const {mainDiv} = useStyles(props);
  // can use as className property
  return <div id="mainDiv" className={mainDiv} />;
};
```

When using a class component and the withStyles higher-order component. You need to extend the props type for your component using the WithStyles type utility. Like so:

```
import { WithStyles, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const styles = (theme: Theme) => createStyles({
  mainDiv: { ...  },
  button: { ... },
  ...
});

interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  foo: number;
  bar: boolean;
}

//or

type Props = WithStyles<typeof styles> & {
  foo: number,
  bar: boolean
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As a hook, useStyles/makeStyles only works for functional components. Are you saying that for a Class component the only solution is to pass the style object to the style attribute?

Comment: The equivalent of `makeStyles` for a class component is the `withStyles` higher order component: https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component

Comment: Yet, that's what we are doing. 
`export default withStyles(styles)(ClassComponent);`
In those docs it still shows passing styles objects to the className prop inside the render function (before wrapping in the higher-order component). E.g., `<div className={props.classes.root} />;` 

But, this is giving me the TypeScript error mentioned in my orig question.

Comment: I added an edit to the answer above that gives the solution using the WithStyles type utility.